# Does having metal safe increase chances of burglary at home

Tags: safety, home-automation, security

One of my friends brought a metal safe recently. However he is also worried that burglars somehow know about existence of such safe on house ( either through metal detectors or some other means ). Also he mentioned that once burglars enter house and see a safe, they try to break it by any means causing much destruction.

Is this true? Is having safe in home actually inviting burglars or serves as actual security against burglars/fire etc.

What are the reasons not to have safe at home

Comment: It’s probably good not to lock your doors either. If they see a locked door they’ll cause a lot of destruction getting in. Likewise with a home security system they’ll know you have something of value on the premises.

Comment: do you really think that burlars have the technology to detect metal in a house and distinguish the difference between a safe and a refrigerator from outside of the house?

Comment: Personally, I recommend leaving a second safe open on the front lawn with $1000 hanging out as a decoy. Do this and you will never have a problem with anyone trying to break into the real safe.

Comment: If you are concerned about burglars being interested in your home, Rolls Royce, BMWs or curtains open with 100" TVs or leaving empty boxes with pictures of expensive stereo equipment is a way to attract them. Leaving valuables in sight is too. Telling frriends and others you have a safe is sure to find it's way to unscrupulous people. Think of it as a "kiss and tell" - don't tell your friends you bought a safe and they wont paste online about you buying a safe (because they wont know you have one)

Comment: I was going to vote to close this but the comment are so great that i decided not to..lol

Comment: You might want to read "Straight" by Dick Francis for some safe ideas. Fiction, but well written, and there are several sorts and the thinking behind them that come into it...the fact that you know your friend bought a safe is not a good sign for your friends safe being unknown to anyone else, of course. And that is "some other means" once the word spreads far enough and is heard in the right ears.

Answer (score 2):

It is safer to have no valuables in the house. But if you do have valuables a safe will slow them down.

In my State firearms have to be secured, most thieves figure that's what's in the safe. Most firearms fetch less than $100, so it isn't really worth the time it takes to break it  open. Cheap safes are easy to open, but thieves also know the cheaper the safe the less valuable the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You might feel the need to tell your friends about it. Or buy it with a credit card, or from a company that will deliver it and perhaps be seen doing so, thus providing information that you have a safe at home.

Word might spread to people who will either rip it out of your house wholesale if small, or force you to open it in the middle of the night by threatening you or your family members if inconveniently large.

It will not be as well secured and protected as an actual bank vault/safe deposit box.